# Using jQuery to submit form from link outside of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hyperlink

I'm trying to submit a form from a link that is located in my nav bar.

I'm new to javascript.jQuery and unsure why this won't execute.

I have a feeling there I need to put something else in the link's href but I'm not sure what it is? I appreciate the feedback and expertise.

LINK

```
<li><a href="#" id="add-product-save-link"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Save</a></li>
```

FORM

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post" id="add-product-form">
```

JAVASCRIPT (this code in an external separate file I have linked to the template)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#add-product-save-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#add-product-form').submit();
    });
});
```

I've linked to jQuery with:

Comment: Have you debugged anything? tried putting `alert` or `console.log` in the code? Are you getting any errors in the console? What exactly isn't working

Comment: It appears the $(document).ready is executing but I'm not executing the code inside $('#add-product-save-link').click(function(e) {

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in pure JavaScript: (http://jsfiddle.net/4enf7/)

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('add-product-form').submit();">Send form</a>
```

Comment: This worked great! Not sure why I couldn't get it execute the other way. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 8):

Link:

```
<a href="#" id="add-product-save-link" class="icon-plus" ><i>Save</i></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#add-product-save-link').click(function() {
        $('#add-product-form').submit();
    });
});
```

You don't need the e.preventDefault(), because your anchor tag isn't going anywhere (the href is `#`).

Because your `<form>` tag's action attribute is blank, that means that the form will submit itself to this same document.  If that is what you want to do, then you can put the logic for that at the top of your document:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        //do your form processing here
    }else{
        //your normal page is here.
    }
?>
```

Finally, because this answer uses jQuery, ensure that you reference the jQuery library somewhere, such as in the `<head>` tags:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are clicking in the "A", not in the Italic (With ID). Supposing you will not change the HTML to that work out you should use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#add-product-save-link').parent().click(function(e) {
        $('#add-product-form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you mean jQuery (not just javascript).

Comment: Your correct I meant jQuery. I changed the link so the id in the "A" but am still not able to execute the code. Any other thoughts? I appreaciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

$("#button").click(function(e){

```
        $.post('url.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data){
```

Comment: 1/ Consider adding at least some words to your code snippet so the OP and future reader of your answer may understand it clearly. 2/ I think this answer is really missing some code, that code would definitely end with a parse error.