# Link button to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to link an input to a button. In the sense that the button will trigger the input, and the input will remain hidden.

Below is a solution I found:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="files" href=""> 
 <button id="uploadDevice" class="button button-block button-positive">
            <i class="icon ion-android-mail"></i> &nbsp; <text id="textBtn1">From Device </text>
</button></a>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  $("#files").click(function(){
        $(this).next().trigger('click');
    });

    </script>
```

Css

```
 <style>
  .uploadDevice{
     visibility : hidden;
  }
```

My issue is as follow: The button and the input MUST have different ID. The above solution works but both the button and the input id must be the same when I need them to differ.

Comment: you shouldn't reuse ids. you can do `$('#id1').click(function () { $('#id2').click() });`

Comment: maybe some usefull information here: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406732/using-jquery-to-submit-form-from-link-outside-of-form)

Comment: thanks I tried, $("#buttonFile").click(function(){
        $("#files").next().trigger('click');
    }); but it does not seem to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="typeHidden" />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Show Me" />
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('#typeHidden').val('Secret text');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/)

---

If you want to have multiple DIV/button combos, and you want the button to update the corresponding DIV, see

[this revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/1/)

Comment: on a side note, lets say i want the function to only be executed once the button has been clicked twice. for example user press button it gets upload to output1, user clicks the button a second time, it gets outputed to output 2, etc

Comment: Please ask this as a new question (just copy / paste this question and make appropriate changes) and you will have several answers within moments. I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: It appears you are afk, Jonathan, and I don't want to keep you waiting if you return several hours from now, so [**here's your answer**](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/2/).  If you put it up as a new question, I'll post the answer there also for credit and for future readers. *Please leave a comment below this one to alert me to look for the new question.*

Comment: thank you so much for your prompt response. I will defintly credit you once the opportunity comes up. One issue i have is that I am using input file isntead text and when trying to apply your update, i encountered a bit of issue http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/8/

Comment: I am not able to make a new post, and I did related to that question, you can go ahead and have your credits upon submission http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975629/output-multiple-input-file-to-a-different-with-a-single-button

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  If you have further questions, please ask anytime. Best wishes for your project.