# Output multiple input file to a different id with a single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In a nutshell,

Below is what I am trying to accomplish:
http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/8/

but as shown I am having issues, it would work as follow:
User clicks on button once, the file gets selected from input and then display in the files_1 id, user clicks on button again, file gets selected, and then output into files_id2,

This part only shows the upload part, in other words, everything mention above beside displaying the image on screen.

Html COde:

```
 <button id="uploadDevice" class="button button-block button-positive">
            <i class="icon ion-android-mail"></i> &nbsp; <text id="textBtn1">From Device </text>
</button>
                <input type="file" class="uploadDevice" id="files_1" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
                <input type="file" class="uploadDevice" id="files_2" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
                <input type="file" class="uploadDevice" id="files_3" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$('#uploadDevice').click(function(){
    myGlobalCounter++;
   $( '#files_' +myGlobalCounter ).val('Secret text ' + myGlobalCounter);
});
```

CSS code:

```
 .uploadDevice{
     visibility : hidden;
  }
```

Update:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box id="uploadedPictures" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
          <ion-slide>

<output id="profilePic1"></output>

  </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
<output id="profilePic2"></output>

  </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
<output id="profilePic3"></output>

  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>


<div class="row">
<div class="col col-50">
     <button id="uploadFacebook" class="button button-block button-positive">
         <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i> &nbsp; <text id="textBtn1"> From Facebook 
</button>
</div>         



<div class="col col-50"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="buttonFile" href=""> 
 <button id="uploadDevice" class="button button-block button-positive">
            <i class="icon ion-android-mail"></i> &nbsp; <text id="textBtn1">From Device </text>
</button></a>
                <input type="file" class="uploadDevice" id="files" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>


    </div>
  </div>

  <style>
  .uploadDevice{
     visibility : hidden;
  }
  </style>

  <script>
  $("#buttonFile").click(function(){
        $("#files").trigger('click');
    });

    </script>
```

script

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
    if (this.files.length > 4) {
        alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    var files = this.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }
        (function(i){
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img id="userPictures" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('profilePic' + (i + 1)).appendChild(span);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        })(i);
    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another version of the 3rd answer.

This one just ***moves*** each FILE INPUT after you click on it, so you can see that the next FILE INPUT is now in place to be clicked.

Basically, instead of using z-index to rotate the just-clicked FILE INPUT to the bottom of the stack, I am moving it down the page so you can visually see what is happening.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nyvkzjba/3/)

Code:

```
var xx, global_cnt = 1;

$('#clicker').button(); //use jQueryUI to auto-style the button

$('div').click(function(){
    xx = global_cnt * 60;
    $('#real_uploader_' +global_cnt).css({'position':'absolute','top':xx+'px'});
    global_cnt++;

    if ( $('#real_uploader_' +global_cnt).length ){
        $('#real_uploader_' +global_cnt).css('z-index','2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="th" id="typeHidden_1" />
<input type="text" class="th" id="typeHidden_2" />
<input type="text" class="th" id="typeHidden_3" />
<input type="text" class="th" id="typeHidden_4" />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Show Me" />
<input type="button" id="nutherbutt" value="Read Hidden Field" />
```

**javasccript/jQuery:**

```
var myGlobalCounter = 0;

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    myGlobalCounter++;
   $( '#typeHidden_' +myGlobalCounter ).val('Secret text ' + myGlobalCounter);
});

$('#nutherbutt').click(function(){
    for (n=1; n<= myGlobalCounter; n++){
        var tmp = $('#typeHidden_' +n).val();
        alert( tmp );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Something like this, but I am using input type file instead and for some reason i seem to be getting an error  http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8conn/8/

Answer (score 0):

I apologize -- I did not read your answer carefully enough the first time.

The `<input type="file" />` element is special. For security reasons, there is very little you can do with javascript to control a file input element. You cannot set the filename programmatically, and you cannot click the button programmatically.

However, there is a work-around that is frequently proposed:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <button><a href="javascript: void(0)">Upload File</a></button>
    <input type="file" id="upload_input" name="upload" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{display:block;width:100px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;}

button{width:110px;height:30px;position:relative;top:-5px;left:-5px;}

input{font-size:50px;width:120px;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity:0); position:relative;top:-40px;left:-20px;background:yellow;}
```

[non-working jsFiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/nyvkzjba/1/)

---

References:

[In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input#answer-3030174)

[Programmatically set the value of a type="file" input HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021526/programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-type-file-input-html-element)

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. so lets see for a work around. I have an input file here, where when the user selects a picture its get displayed to a different ID up to 3 times. Like theres 3 output, and each output relates to an id, the problem i have is that it only outputs to the first one, and any other pictures fall right beside it and not at a different id. I have included an update under my initial postr

Comment: By the way -- this may not be relevant, but -- the most useful file upload utility of which I am aware, is Ravishanker Kusuma's `jQuery File Upload plugin`: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: Okay, this probably isn't what you are asking either, but I re-styled (improved) the example in the above answer: http://jsfiddle.net/nyvkzjba/1/

Comment: @JonathanEtienne See the third answer to this question (also by me) -- it may be closer to what you want.

Comment: thank you this should help do the trick. appreciate. sorry this my small last request, how do I set the width of an item in javascript in terms of % for example http://jsfiddle.net/UTp4T/43/ I want the width of the image to be  100%

Comment: Try this:  `.attr("width", "100%")`  *These are css statements, so they need either `px` or `%` or `em` after them.* - http://jsfiddle.net/UTp4T/45/

Comment: thats my concern when i add % it doesnt load

Comment: It should... it's just a `css` parameter.  `100%` should work -- keep fiddling with it...

Comment: @JonathanEtienne - **OH WAIT** -- *if the image is larger than the container, the image will be invisible...* Maybe that's what's happening...?

Comment: how would I have the container be 100% as well>?

Comment: ah, yeah, there's a problem. You know what? You're really limited with `li`, `ul` and (unrelated, but important) `span`. Very difficult to manipulate height, width, margin-top, etc. with these elements. *I suggest switching to DIVs instead* Honestly, they are just as easy to work with once you get started -- and *so much more *stylable**

Comment: thanks. I follow your advice and made some minor adjustments. but the problem persist : http://jsfiddle.net/UTp4T/52/

Comment: Okay, if I understand your code, your AJAX block gets back some data: `result`.  What data type is it?  If JSON, you need to convert it into an object with `var myObj = JSON.parse(result);` -- but the `result` data *must* be valid JSON, so be sure of that. Next, where did `this.image` come from? What is `this` in the context? How did you get `image` out of the `result` data?  *I think you have to either (1) receive the data in text/html and break it into strings, or (2) receive the data (`result`) as json and parse it into an object/array.*

Comment: I think you are correct, 2) receive the data (result) as json and parse it into an object/array. this.image is referring to the images defined

Comment: Yup, I know what you mean. I was asking how you get the actual *value* - what does the variable `this.image` contain? I don' think it has any value yet... that's what I'm saying. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me try again.

I was having some difficulty understanding what you need.  If I can get my head around that, then I'm pretty sure I can help.

Please check if this is what you need.

This code has 3 `<input type="file" >` elements. All 3 are "invisible" *(using opacity, to they remain where they are on screen, they are just invisible).*

The FILE inputs are also stacked on top of each other. At the start, input_1 is on top --- but it is invisible, so all you see is the BUTTON underneath it.

When "the button" (really, input_1) is clicked, three things happen:

(1) the OPEN dialog *(Choose a file to upload)* is displayed for input_1

(2) global_cnt is used to move input_1 to the back (using z-index)

(3) global_cnt is incremented, and then used again to move input_2 to the front

(4) global_cnt is now at the correct number to move input_2 to back when it is clicked

Each time the user clicks "the button" (really, they are clicking an invisible `input type="file"` element), a different input element is moved to the top. Therefore, by clicking the same "button", the user keeps uploading to a different file input.

Note: this works because when you click `input_1`, the `div` also gets the click event (through event bubbling).

[jsFiddle Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/nyvkzjba/2/)

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="clicker" value="Upload File" />
    <input type="file" class="hidden_uploaders" id="real_uploader_1" name="upload_1" />
    <input type="file" class="hidden_uploaders" id="real_uploader_2" name="upload_2" />
    <input type="file" class="hidden_uploaders" id="real_uploader_3" name="upload_3" />
</div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var global_cnt = 1;

$('#clicker').button(); //use jQueryUI to auto-style the button

$('div').click(function(){
    if ( $('real_uploader_' +global_cnt).length ) $('real_uploader_' +global_cnt).css('z-index','-1');
    global_cnt++;
    if ( $('real_uploader_' +global_cnt).length ) $('real_uploader_' +global_cnt).css('z-index','2');
});
```

*still working on this*